# Как заполнить пропуски в столбце?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, обработка-данных, nan

Нужно заполнить пропуски в столбце `year` значениями, которые уже известны для других платформ.

Возможно ли это сделать используя только pandas?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['Call of Duty 3', np.nan,'PC'], ['Call of Duty 3', 2006,'Wii'], ['LEGO Harry Potter: Years 5-7', 2012,'PS2'],['LEGO Harry Potter: Years 5-7',np.nan,'X360']], columns=['name', 'year','platform'])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df.loc[df["year"].isna(), "year"] = \
    df.loc[df["year"].isna(), "name"].map(df.groupby("name")["year"].first())
```

результат:

```
In [69]: df
Out[69]: 
                           name    year platform
0                Call of Duty 3  2006.0       PC
1                Call of Duty 3  2006.0      Wii
2  LEGO Harry Potter: Years 5-7  2012.0      PS2
3  LEGO Harry Potter: Years 5-7  2012.0     X360
```